# Game stops when button is clicked to serialize data and change scene, but no error log from Unity

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

As you can see in the title, When I run my game in the Unity editor, I click a button after entering a username into an input field that serializes the name and loads the next scene. The problem is that when I click the button, the game freezes and Unity stop responding, but when I remove the code that serializes the name, it loads the next level no problem. I have attached the code that gets the name from the input field, the code that serializes the name and the code that loads the next scene in that order. The problem is most likely in the serializing code, but I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. I edited the code and replaced the code below as Yuri Galiza requested. To see the problem first hand and to get some better context as to what the code is doing, please use this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BynpT6Viy1xdR0IwWmV6T3RRU2s?usp=sharing

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class getUserName : MonoBehaviour
{

public InputField mainInputField;
public string userName;
public static getUserName current;

public void SetName()
{
    userName = mainInputField.text;

    Debug.Log(userName);

    GameObject NameSaver = GameObject.Find("NameSaver");
    SaveName saveName = NameSaver.GetComponent<SaveName>();
    SaveName.nameSave();
}
}


using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveName : MonoBehaviour
{

public static string PlayerName;

public static List<getUserName> names = new List<getUserName>();

public static void nameSave()
{

    Debug.Log("Saving");

    GameObject InputField = GameObject.Find("InputField");
    getUserName GetUserName = InputField.GetComponent<getUserName>();
    GetUserName.SetName();
    PlayerName = GetUserName.userName;

    Debug.Log("PlayerName");

    names.Add(getUserName.current);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.torlon");
    bf.Serialize(file, SaveName.names);
    file.Close();

    Debug.Log("Saved");
}

public static void nameLoad()
{

    Debug.Log("Loading");

    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.torlon"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/savedGames.torlon", FileMode.Open);
        SaveName.names = (List<getUserName>)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Load failed");
    }
}
}


using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ButtonManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public int NextScene;

public void OnClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading level");
        SceneManager.LoadScene(NextScene);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably the application is dying before the Log is called. Try placing logs at different places throughout the code. And then you'll probably find the place with the problem.

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, so I may be wrong, but it's very likely to be in the code that serializes the data. It may be due to me scripting it wrong, or it may be due to the game trying to serialize and load another scene at the same time and breaking. I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I've got some good news and some bad news. For some reason, it's no longer breaking on me, but I'm getting an error when I press the button: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SaveName.nameSave () (at Assets/scripts/SaveName.cs:22)
getUserName.SetName () (at Assets/scripts/getUserName.cs:23)

Comment: shouldn't SaveName.nameSave() be saveName.nameSave()

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does looks like you have placed them in the wrong order.

Comment: Just noticed that. Thanks for bringing that up. As well as fixing that, I changed the code to load the scene asynchronously, but I'm not seeing anything popping up in the console from the code that serializes that data and the scene in which you input the username does not go away and instead, it just stays there on top of the new scene. I'll add a link to a google drive with the entire game so far shortly. Check the question to find it.

Comment: Another thing I just noticed that may be causing the problem; when I check the SaveName property in the buttons' OnClick() area, I see this: <Missing SaveName.nameLoad> instead of the name of the void that I set to start when the button is clicked. I have attached the SaveName code as well as all the other scripts I have posted in this question to an object as you can see if you get the game from the google drive link I posted. Also, I ended up commenting out the code that starts the saveName.nameSave() void due to an error that arose when I did it.